# How to center button on HTML?

Tags: html, css, css-float

I am new to this so please excuse me.

I am working on my first website coding and, I am having so much difficulties with centering my button. I want to place the button on the middle of the window.

I will attach the code below:

```css
/* Hide Scroll */

html, body {
            overflow:hidden;
           }

/* Home Page - Background Image */

body {
        background: url(Image-2.jpg);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        position: relative;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        min-width: 100%;
        min-height: 100%;
     }

/* Mains */

#Mains-Logo {
            margin-top: 42px;
            margin-left: 80px;
            }

#Mains-Basket {
                float: right;
                margin-top: 48px;
                margin-right: 96px;
              }

#Mains-SP {
            text-align: center;
            margin-top: 785px;
            margin-left:810px;
          }

/* Button */

.Button-SN {
            text-align: center;
            min-height: 100%;
            min-width: auto;
           }

.SN {
    border: 5px solid #fcfcfc;
    padding: 8px 25px;
    margin: auto;
    }
```

```html
<body>
    <img id="Mains-Logo" src="Logo.png">
    <img id="Mains-Basket" src="Basket.png">

 <!-- THIS RIGHT HERE -->
  
    <div class="Button-SN">
        <a class="SN" href="#">SHOP NOW</a>
    </div>
 
<!-- END -->  
  
</body>

<footer>
    <a href="#"><img id="Mains-SP" src="SP.png"></a>
</footer>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to center a <div> on a page vertically and horizontally?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356809/best-way-to-center-a-div-on-a-page-vertically-and-horizontally)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the wrapper `.Button-SN`.

Add:

```
.SN{ 
  position:absolute; 
  display: inline-block;
  top:50%; 
  left:50%; 
  width:150px; 
  border: 5px solid #fcfcfc; 
  line-height: 40px; 
  margin-top:-20px; 
  margin-left:-75px; 
}
```

Comment: Also make sure to have the entire document and body occupy the full height of the window: `html, body{ min-height:100%; height:100%;  }`

Comment: Absolute star! Really appreciate your help and everybody else who gave me suggestions on how I could resolve this!

Comment: There are many ways to achieve what you wanted; it only depends of the context. Glad to help :)

Answer (score 2):

This question has already been answered in stack overflow, here are some useful links to solve your problem.

[align text in middle/center of page and button on bottom/center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25129497/align-text-in-middle-center-of-page-and-button-on-bottom-center)

[How to center a button within a div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7560832/how-to-center-a-button-within-a-div)

[trying to align html button at the center of the my page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11799159/trying-to-align-html-button-at-the-center-of-the-my-page)

[How to center html element in browser window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982054/how-to-center-html-element-in-browser-window)

Comment: Since you are in a learning process and others have faced the same problem, its better for you to learn how it works from other stack overflow response. That is why I posted links for you to learn from.

Comment: As I consider you are a beginner here on Stackoverflow (because of your rep) I think your answer should be a comment or you should vote this question as duplicate..

Comment: Ok, that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
vertical-align:middle;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
.Button-SN {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Absolute star! Really appreciate your help and everybody else who gave me suggestions on how I could resolve this!

Answer (score 0):

Use `clear:both` to clear  floated direction.

```
.Button-SN {
    clear: both;
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Method #01:**

Wrap both images in a `div` and set layout of parent with `overflow: hidden`.

```css
/* Hide Scroll */

html, body {
    overflow:hidden;
}

/* Home Page - Background Image */

body {
    background: url(Image-2.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}

/* Mains */
.image-holder {
    overflow: hidden;
}

#Mains-Logo {
    margin-top: 42px;
    margin-left: 80px;
}

#Mains-Basket {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 48px;
    margin-right: 96px;
}

#Mains-SP {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 785px;
    margin-left:810px;
}

/* Button */

.Button-SN {
    text-align: center;
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: auto;
}

.SN {
    border: 5px solid #fcfcfc;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 8px 25px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="image-holder">
        <img id="Mains-Logo" src="Logo.png">
        <img id="Mains-Basket" src="Basket.png">
    </div>

 <!-- THIS RIGHT HERE -->
  
    <div class="Button-SN">
        <a class="SN" href="#">SHOP NOW</a>
    </div>
 
<!-- END -->  
  
</body>

<footer>
    <a href="#"><img id="Mains-SP" src="SP.png"></a>
</footer>
```

**Method #02:**

Add `clear: both` to the styles of `.Button-SN`.

```css
/* Hide Scroll */

html, body {
    overflow:hidden;
}

/* Home Page - Background Image */

body {
    background: url(Image-2.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}

/* Mains */

#Mains-Logo {
    margin-top: 42px;
    margin-left: 80px;
}

#Mains-Basket {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 48px;
    margin-right: 96px;
}

#Mains-SP {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 785px;
    margin-left:810px;
}

/* Button */

.Button-SN {
    text-align: center;
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: auto;
    clear: both;
}

.SN {
    border: 5px solid #fcfcfc;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 8px 25px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <img id="Mains-Logo" src="Logo.png">
    <img id="Mains-Basket" src="Basket.png">

 <!-- THIS RIGHT HERE -->
  
    <div class="Button-SN">
        <a class="SN" href="#">SHOP NOW</a>
    </div>
 
<!-- END -->  
  
</body>

<footer>
    <a href="#"><img id="Mains-SP" src="SP.png"></a>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your button CSS:

```
display: flex;
justify-content: center; /*centers items on the line (the x-axis by default)*/
align-items: center; /*centers items on the cross-axis (y by default)*/
position:absolute;
```

Let me know how you get on!

Thanks